# Couldn't find executable named jet_real.launch below /home/nvidia/FOLDER_FOR_ROS/catkin_ws/src/rosjet/jet_bringup [rosrun]

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone sorry for this long question I am pretty new with ROS, I am trying to connect my jetson TX! with my host pc. However when I run my launch file

```
source ~/.bashrc; source FOLDER_FOR_ROS/catkin_ws/devel/setup.sh; rosrun jet_bringup jet_real.launch
```

I get this error:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named jet_real.launch below /home/nvidia/FOLDER_FOR_ROS/catkin_ws/src/rosjet/jet_bringup
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/nvidia/FOLDER_FOR_ROS/catkin_ws/src/rosjet/jet_bringup/launch/jet_real.launch

when I run catkin config I get this:
Profile:                     default
Extending:             [env] /home/nvidia/FOLDER_FOR_ROS/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/nvidia
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source Space:      [missing] /home/nvidia/src
Log Space:         [missing] /home/nvidia/logs
Build Space:       [missing] /home/nvidia/build
Devel Space:       [missing] /home/nvidia/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/nvidia/install
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Initialized new catkin workspace in `/home/nvidia`
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: Source space `/home/nvidia/src` does not yet exist.
```

I already check my jetson and Pc can ping, but I think that this problem come from directories path
I will really appreciate your help thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295685/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-jet_real.launch-below-/home/nvidia/folder_for_ros/catkin_ws/src/rosjet/jet_bringup-%5Brosrun%5D-found-the-following,-but-they%27re-either-not-files/) by [Luis Jibaja](https://answers.ros.org/users/36158/luis-jibaja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're using

```
rosrun jet_bringup jet_real.launch
```

to start a *launch file*. `rosrun` expects an executable, which a launch file *isn't*. Take a look at the error

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named jet_real.launch below /home/nvidia/FOLDER_FOR_ROS/catkin_ws/src/rosjet/jet_bringup
```

You need to use `roslaunch` instead

```
roslaunch jet_bringup jet_real.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0